# Error 404 on page after adding new code in controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404, asp.net-core-2.2

I added a new controller for a new model with its view and everything worked fine as default but when I added some code, it broke the page and now when I try to open it, I get the error 404. 
If I remove that code, I still get the error and I can't go back to default.

I tried the same thing on an other controller getting the same effect.

I tried creating the controller with Entity framework and without with the same results.

My other controller works fine for displaying data but creating data in database with this controller does not work.

**The controller that doesn't work:**

```
public class AccessController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataAccess data;


    public AccessController(DataAccess data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(AccessModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var CurrentUserName = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
            List<ApplicationUser> users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            var userData = data.LoadUser();
            string userID = null;

            foreach (var row in userData)
            {
                users.Add(new ApplicationUser
                {
                    MachineId = row.MachineId,
                    Email = row.Email
                });
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < users.Count; j++)
            {
                if (users[j].Email == CurrentUserName)
                    userID = users[j].MachineId;
            }

            AccessProcessor.CreateAccess(userID, model.OpenValve, model.OpenTrap,
                model.OpenFeedingPen, model.StartMachine, data);
        }
        return View();
    }

}
```

**Configure in startup:**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**appsettings.json:**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MVCCoreAppDB": "The connection string"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you you have decorated your `Create` action with `HttpPost`. The reason why you are getting 404 error is because you don't have a `Create` action which serves as `Get`. All you have to do is add another action as:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var model = new AccessModel();
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Errff it was so simple... Thank you so much. I now understand a little bit better how the controller works.